# Performance looping arrayList vs POJO (JAVA)

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, pojo

My question is about the performance at the time of traversing an ArrayList vs POJO, that is, if I take the data from the database and charge it to the ArrayList and then to a POJO:

Is it more efficient (at the processing level) to traverse the ArrayList (position [0], [1], ...) or POJO (pojo.nombre, pojo.lastname, ..)?

Example looping the ArrayList:

```
private List<Object[]> _listaClientes = new ArrayList<Object[]>();//create arrayList
public void cargaClientes(){
    try{
        _listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
        //take data from DB:
        _listaClientes = ctrClientes.getData();

        //Loop arrayList:
        for(Object[] obj : _listaClientes){
            System.out.println(obj[0]);//id
            System.out.println(obj[1]);//name
            //...
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Example looping POJO:

```
private List<Cliente> listaClientes;
public void cargaClientes(){
    try{
        //take data from DB:
        listaClientes = ctrClientes.getDataPojo();

        //looping POJO
        Iterator<Cliente> itrCli = listaClientes.iterator();
        while(itrCli.hasNext()){
            Cliente cli = itrCli.next();
            System.out.println(cli.cedula);//id
            System.out.println(cli.nombre);//name
            //...
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: But you need to use a collection of `Object` where the POJO return the correct type value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructing an Object (`Cliente`) is not free and has overheads involved, so the POJO is likely to be slower.

However, the difference is likely to be unnoticeable. In all performance cases, you should write the code that makes the most sense first and then IF it’s a bottleneck, consider improving it. And in all cases you MUST benchmark to ensure that you have improved it, and that the gains you’ve made are worth it.

In addition, working with a POJO is much more likely to reduce the number of errors and make it easier to work with in future. Consider the following - which one jumps of the page as being wrong?

`something.acceptAge(cli[1])`

`something.acceptAge(cliente.getLastName())`

Comment: Thank you @Jackg it helps me a lot.